# Pairs in Balaam's blessings

Tags: song-poetry, parashat-balak

In all of Balaam's blessings, nearly every phrase is repeated in similar wording. For example:

> Arise, Balak, and hear - listen closely to me, son of Zippor.
>
> God is not a man that He should lie - nor is He a mortal that He should relent.
>
> Would He say and not do - speak and not fulfill?
>
> I have received [an instruction] to bless - and bless, I cannot retract it.
>
> He does not look at evil in Jacob - and has seen no perversity in Israel
>
> the Lord, his God, is with him - and he has the King's friendship.

(Bamidbar 22:18-21, translation: [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951))

While repetition is fairly common in Biblical poetry, the pattern here of nearly perfect pairs is unusual. Is there an explanation of this?

Comment: I was going to answer that this method is common in Biblical "poetry" until you mentioned that, so I'm requesting that you expand on what you find more "unusual" here, than elsewhere.

Comment: @DanF As mentioned, here nearly every verse in all three blessings (about 15-20 verses in total) is split into pairs. In other places, such parallelism is not nearly as consistent.

Comment: Iyov Ch 3, Haazinu, some chapters in Psalms... It's quite common.  Maybe Bilaam was just a better poet?